# how do i publish text and picture to Facebook news feed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am pretty new at incorporating Facebook into iOS apps.  I have read 3 books, studied the Facebook examples, and studies the Facebook tutorials, and I don't understand Facebook integration.  I understand how to register the app with Facebook, but what I don't understand is the code to post text and a picture to a user's news feed.  I have tried to understand Facebook's tutorials, but they are all based on Xcode and iOS versions which are not current.  Facebook's tutorials are also not consistent (e.g., the login tutorial does not match variables with the posting tutorial, etc.).  I do understand how to add text to "initialText", but it's against Facebook policy to provide default text in this variable.  Can anyone explain how to publish text and a picture to a user's news feed in Xcode?

Thanx!

Comment: Do you want to use the native framework offered by apple?

Comment: I could do that, yes.  I have been trying to understand Facebook's, but I would accept that using apple's framework.

Comment: Does anyone have a example which uses Facebook's framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import social framework in your project.

```
- (void)ShareOnFB    
{         
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
            //Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS

        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

    NSString *fb=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you can add your text hereand change it as and when needed"];

    [controller setInitialText:fb];      



    //Adding the Image to the facebook post value from iOS

    [controller addImage:yourImageView.image];


    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];


}
```

Comment: I thought this: [controller setInitialText:fb];  Was not acceptable to Facebook policy?

Comment: yeah this should post the image and text on fb. you can change the initial text dynamically instead of static text.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
                if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                    NSLog(@"ResultCancelled");

                } else

                {
                    NSLog(@"ResultSuccess");
                }

                [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
            };
            controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
            [controller setInitialText:@"Learn iOS6 Social Framework integration"];
            [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
            [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpeg"]];
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

        }
        else{

            //NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                                          message:[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"The application cannot post message at the moment. Please login under setting section with your Facebook account."]
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
```